# Need some help in my AngularJS learning

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have some html-code

```
<div ng-controller="aboutController">
    <p ng-repeat="name in about">
        {{about.name}}
        {{about.surname}}
    </p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('about.json').success(function(data) {
            console.log('this is data:',data);
            $scope.about = data;
        });
    });
</script>
```

what which derective I must to write, simply to insert data from a json-file without repeating them?

Comment: Please elaborate your problem. Is `data` an array?

Comment: my json-file
{
 "name" : "Peter",
 "surname" : "Chpoksky"
}
and ng-repeat is repeating data and I need only to insert data from json to html, without repeating

Comment: Get delete `ng-repeat="name in about"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any directive. Just remove [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) and use

```
<p>
    {{about.name}}
    {{about.surname}}
</p>
```

[`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) is generally used with collection.

> The ngRepeat directive instantiates a template once per item from a collection.

Answer (score 0):

problem is "about." try as "name."
Try as below:

```
<p ng-repeat="name in about">
            {{name.name}}
            {{name.surname}}
        </p>
```